# Работа с MySql базами в PHP

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

А можно ли в ПХП сравнивать данные из двух таблиц сразу? К примеру, есть таблица в базе users и в той же базе comments. В первой таблице есть поле id, а во второй com_id. Можно ли их сравнить если подключить сразу обе таблицы в запросе?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Для чего вы хотите сравнивать ? Может вы имели ввиду обьединить ? Так это не от PHP зависит. В запросе к базе данных вы можете обьединить две таблицы (или больше), например из вашего примера user.id и comment.com_id, в результате, можно будет получить пользователей и относящиеся к ним комментарии (если конечно такая логика была заложена в базе данных). Затем уже с помощью PHP можно будет обработать эти данные.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$com_id=15;
$id = 1;
$q = ''
  .'SELECT *'
  .' FROM users AS T1'
  .' JOIN comments AS T2'
  .' WHERE T1.id='.$id
  .' AND T2.com_id='.$com_id
  .' LIMIT 1;';
$res = mysql_query($q);
if ($result = mysql_fetch_object($res))
  var_dump($result);
?>
```

А вообще да, можно ж и без джойнов. Сравнить можно и прямым обращением:

```
[ ... ] WHERE users.id = comments.com_id [...]
```

Comment: Множественный SELECT из нескольких таблиц в MySQL - то же самое, что JOIN.